# Storing google coordinates in to an mysqli database but it stores only zeros

Tags: php, mysqli

My problem is what the title says my table rowsetting are float 16,11 for the lat and long
the others are varchar the strange thing is that i echo out the value and that gives me exactly what i'am exspecting but in the database it shows 0,00000000. the other values are stored correct anyone suggestions i'am new at php msql thanks

```
<?php require_once("includes/myDataBaseConnection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php


 //postcode omzetten naar coordinaten
function lookup($string){

     $string = str_replace (" ", "+", urlencode($string));
     $details_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:".$string."|country:nl&sensor=false";
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);


     // If Status Code is ZERO_RESULTS, OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, REQUEST_DENIED or INVALID_REQUEST
     if ($response['status'] != 'OK') {
      return null;
     }


    $geometry = $response['results'][0]['geometry'];
    $plaats = $response['results'][0]['address_components'][2]['long_name'];
    $provincie = $response['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['long_name'];
    $longitude = (float)$geometry['location']['lat'];
    $latitude =  (float)$geometry['location']['lng'];

    $mapCor = array(
        'latitude' => (float)$geometry['location']['lng'],
        'longitude' => (float)$geometry['location']['lat'],
       // 'location_type' => $geometry['location_type'],
        'plaats' => $response['results'][0]['address_components'][2]['long_name'],
        'provincie' => $response['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['long_name']
    );

    return $mapCor;

}
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];



    $mapCor = lookup($postcode);




//query opslaan

    foreach ($mapCor as $key => $value) {
    print($value);  

    $query  = "INSERT INTO markers (";
    $query .= "lat, lng, address, provincie";
    $query .= ") VALUES (";
    $query .= " '$value', '$value', '$value', '$value' ";
    $query .= ")";
}
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if ($result) {
        print ("succes!");

        //redirect_to("testGoogleMaps.php");
    }   else {
        // Failure
        print ("Subject creation failed.");


    }

        if (isset($connection)) { mysqli_close($connection); }

    ?>`enter code here`
```

Comment: In your `foreach` loop you generate the insert statement four times, but put the same `$value` into each field. Only the last iteration is used for the query on the next line.

Comment: Thx for your fast reply your right i looked over that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$mapCor = lookup($postcode);

foreach ($mapCor as $key => $value) {
    print($value);  
}
$query  = '
    INSERT INTO markers ( `lat`, `lng`, `address`, `provincie`)
    VALUES ( \''.$mapCor['latitude'].'\', \''.$mapCor['longitude'].'\', \''.$mapCor['plaats'].'\', \''.$mapCor['provincie'].'\')
';
```

Comment: I would consider using a mixture of `"`, `'`, and maybe even `\`` to make things more legible.

Comment: Hi Floris thx for your fast reply this is the solution thx a lot i'am new to the syntax so it's a bit of a struggle but i will keep your comment in mind again thx a lot.

Comment: @Floris I would suggest use PDO + prepare, and avoid ' at all :-P